# Copying files in fileshare with Azure Data Factory configuration problem

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-factory

I am trying to learn using the Azure Data Factory to copy data (a collection of csv files in a folder structure) from an Azure File Share to a Cosmos DB instance.

In Azure Data factory I'm creating a "copy data" activity and try to set my file share as source using the following host:

`mystorageaccount.file.core.windows.net\\mystoragefilesharename`

When trying to test the connection, I get the following error:

`[{"code":9059,"message":"File path 'E:\\approot\\mscissstorage.file.core.windows.net\\mystoragefilesharename' is not supported. Check the configuration to make sure the path is valid."}]`

Should I move the data to another storage type like a blob or I am not entering the correct host url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the link posted by [Nicolas Zhang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10646221/nicolas-zhang): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system#sample-linked-service-and-dataset-definitions and the examples provided therein, I was able to solve it an successfully create the copy action. I had two errors (I'm configuring via the data factory UI and not directly the JSON):

1. In the host path, the correct one should be: `\\mystorageaccount.file.core.windows.net\mystoragefilesharename\myfolderpath`
2. The username and password must be the one corresponding to the storage account and not to the actual user's account which I was erroneously using.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to specify the host in json file like this "\\myserver\share" if you create pipeline with JSON directly or you use set the host url like this "\myserver\share" if you're using UI to setup pipeline.

Here is more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system#sample-linked-service-and-dataset-definitions

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction - I've figured it out and posting a reply.

Comment: I think you got that swapped.  In the UI I  started with \\

Answer (score 1):

I believe when you create file linked service, you might choose public IR. If you choose public IR, local path (e.g c:\xxx, D:\xxx) is not allowed, because the machine that run your job is managed by us, which not contains any customer data. Please use self-hosted IR to copy your local files.

Comment: No, I was trying to use an _Azure_ file share as a dataset source, not a local one...